# Linking a results page to details page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

This is my results page, and I need help linking each restaurant to a detail.php page.

I'm working on a website that shows all the restaurants in San Francisco with their health inspection scores, address and violations.

The first page is my index page, and it's just a search bar that allows you to type in the name or keyword of a restaurant. This leads to my results.php page which takes all the data and gives you a list of the matched examples to your search. The problem I'm having is that from the results.php page I have to link it to my details.php for each restaurant that is listed. Then the details page would show their health inspection score, address and map of the restaurant.

How do I link the restaurants to the details page?

This is my website link: http://jfol.io/j426/s13/mariana/a07/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>A07</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Armata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="left-nav">

<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="results.php">Restaurants</a>
<a href="details.php">Violations</a>
<a href="#">Scores</a>

</div>

<div id="main">
<?php

// load query

$query = "

SELECT  businesses.business_id                AS    business_id,
                businesses.name               AS     name,
                inspections.score             AS    score,
                inspections.date              AS     date,     
                inspections.business_id

FROM             businesses

INNER JOIN      inspections

ON                      businesses.business_id = inspections.business_id

WHERE           businesses.name LIKE '%$business_name%'

ORDER BY         businesses.name ASC

LIMIT            $row_start, $pagination";

// output page header

echo "<h1> Restaurants </h1>";

// output query (debug)

 //echo "<i>Debug:</i> " . $query . "<p></p>";

// execute query

$result     = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);

// grab count of records returned

$row_count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// output record count

echo "Displaying records " . ($row_start + 1) . " to " . ($row_start + $pagination) . " <p></p>";

// advance pagination counter

$row_start = $row_start + $pagination;

// output pagination link

echo ("<p></p><a href=\"results.php\">First page</a> | <a href=\"results.php?row_start=" . $row_start . "\">Next " . $pagination . " records</a><p></p>");

// create table tag

echo ("<table>\n\n");

echo ("<tr class=\"header\">\n<td>Business Name</td><td>Inspection Score</td><td>Inspection Date</td></tr>\n");

// create row counter

$current_row = 0;

// loop through returned records

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

// set variables

    $business_id            =   $row["business_id"];
    $business_name          =   ucwords(strtolower($row["name"]));
    $inspection_score       =   $row["score"];

    //$address              =   $row["address"];

    $violation_date         =   date("n/j/Y",strtotime($row["date"]));

    $inspection_date            =   date("n/j/Y",strtotime($row["date"]));

// output to screen

// echo($business_name . " / " . $violation_description . " / " . $violation_date . "<br />");

if ($current_row % 2 == 0)

{

$shading = "alternate ";

}

else

{

$shading = "";

}

echo ("<tr class=\"$shading\">\n\n");

echo("<td>\n\n" . $business_name . "</td>\n\n<td>\n\n" . $inspection_score . "</td>\n\n<td>\n\n" . $inspection_date . "</td>\n\n" );

echo ("</tr>\n\n");

$current_row++;

}

echo ("</table>\n\n");

// output pagination link

echo ("<p></p><a href=\"results.php\">First page</a> | <a href=\"results.php?row_start=" . $row_start . "\">Next " . $pagination . " records</a><p></p>");

?>`enter code here`

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without too much looking, you may want to consider using the ID of each restaurant as part of your link. For example, <a href="details.php?rid=123">Restaurant Name</a>. Also, do consider being careful about single quotes as they're a prime tool for SQL injection. To see an issue, do a search for "Chili's".

Comment: I like the idea for the site.

Comment: @user2962248: please use the `edit` button above, rather than creating a new question. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer, I agree with you--I'd rather see code posted here too, especially when it's so easy to do so.

Comment: @user2962248: also, please refresh your screen before editing. Have a look at the edit history: you overwrote my improvements to your question.

Answer (score 1):

i assume each restaurant has an id in your db

your results page would add a link for each

```
<a herf="details.php?id=i23">the food shack</a>
```

on details.php use the id to query the db

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : null;
SELECT * from foo where id=$id
```

Answer (score 1):

When you populate the results on your results page, you most likely have a unique record ID for each restaurant. You'll want to add that ID to a link within the loop in the table you generated, with something like this.

```
<td><a href="/details.php?id=<?= $r['id'] ?><?= $r['name'] ?></a></td>
```